# array_push for a non array value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make the array of some variable generate in a for loop.$priManagerId=516 for first time,346 for second time and 675 for third time and so on. but I got the wrong array of last value.How to get the value like(516,346,675,...,1599)

```
protected $priManagerId = array ();
foreach($proOwnerPM as $PriManager){
             if($PriManager->manager_aceid!='')
             {
              $priManagerId= DB::table ('users')->where('aceid','=',$PriManager->manager_aceid)->first()->id;   
              print_r( $priManagerId); //516
              $priManagerId=(array)$priManagerId;

              array_push($priManagerId,$priManagerId);

             }
            }
            var_dump($priManagerId);

  output
  array (size=2)
  0 => int 1599
  1 => 
     array (size=1)
       0 => int 1599  //last value
```

Answer (score 0):

change   `$priManagerId= DB::table` to   `$userId= DB::table` .you have defined same variable name to array and db response

```
protected $priManagerId = array ();
foreach($proOwnerPM as $PriManager){
             if($PriManager->manager_aceid!='')
             {
              $userId= DB::table ('users')->where('aceid','=',$PriManager->manager_aceid)->first()->id;   
              print_r(  $userId); //516


              array_push($priManagerId, $userId);

             }
            }
            var_dump($priManagerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to fill your array by adding '[]' after the array name.
Like that:

```
$priManagerId[] = DB::table ('users')->where('aceid','=',$PriManager->manager_aceid)->first()->id;
```

It will auto fill the array as you're looking for.
Then, you don't need 'array_push' function.

Hope it helps you :)